# Implementing parallel-for in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I would like to implement a parallel-for in on hadoop. Basically parallel-for receives  a sub-skeleton (it could be a function like map() ) and an integer as parameters. the sub-skeleton will be executed the number of times specified by the integer parameter. The result of one invocation of a sub-skeleton is passed as a parameter to the following invocation of the sub-skeleton. Eventually the result of the last sub-skeleton is provided as the parallel-for result.  A sample of the implementation on a Scandium library (http://skandium.niclabs.cl/) is below and I would love to port this implementation on hadoop.

```
* @param <P> The input and result type of the {@link Skeleton}.
* */
public class For<P> extends AbstractSkeleton<P,P> {

    Skeleton<P,P> subskel;
    int times;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * 
     * @param skeleton The skeleton pattern to execute.
     * @param times The number of times to execute the skeleton.
     */
    public For(Skeleton<P,P> skeleton, int times){
        this.subskel=skeleton;
        this.times = times;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * 
     * @param execute The skeleton pattern to execute.
     * @param times The number of times to execute the {@link Muscle}.
     */
    public For(Execute<P,P> execute, int times){
        this(new Seq<P,P>(execute), times);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void accept(SkeletonVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't undersand your question. You want to run some function f() a constant number of times, passing the result of the previous run to the current run each time? What part of that should be parallel? Can you be more specific about what your overall goal is, there may be a simple existing tool that helps.

Comment: In hadoop the input is split to different workstation and the same function is applied to all the workstation at the same time. Thats the parallel part of it. The only thing I need to worry about is to implement that function in a sequentially way. Algorithm skeleton frameworks handles the complexity of parallism. MapReduce(Hadoop) is one of the frameworks.

Comment: To pass the results of a Map function into a new Map function, you'd have to chain the Mappers... What it sounds like might work is to have a loop inside the mapper which did processing, then combined/finished the result in a reducer?

Comment: A loop inside the Mapper or a loop inside the new Pfor function? eg.
Pfor(map(),data, int 4){
for i = 0 to i=3 do
data.map();
}
??? Is that what you refering to or the loop has to be inside the mapper class itself?

Comment: Any more ideas on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to execute a function N times, with each invocation receiving as input the output of the previous invocation.

This chaining of function calls is, by its nature, serial.  There's no (general) way to parallelize it.

The only hope I can see would be if the nature of the function and inputs (which you haven't specified) allows a single invocation of the function to be parallelized, then you could do that, and do the iteration/chaining at the job control level. This is to say:  If your input is a data set, and your function is some transformation on that data set, the output of which is legitimate input to the function, and if this transformation can be parallelized, then there might be a way to use Hadoop here.

If you can provide more detail, I'll be happy to update this answer with more specific suggestions.